# How do I set a bash script's positional arguments from stdin?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that I wish to read from a file to get it's arguments set. Basically my script reads arguments positionally (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.)

```
while test $# -gt 0; do
  case $1 in
    -h | --help)
      echo "Help cruft"
      exit 0
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

One of the options I was hoping could be a config file that reads in arguments (for simple and easy *config*) so I was hoping the `set --` command would work (`--` to over ride the arguments). However, since they are defined in a file I have to read it in and use `xargs` to pass them:

```
-c | --config)
  cat $2 | xargs set --
  continue
  ;;
```

The trouble is that xargs buggers up the `--` so I don't know how to accomplish this.

Note: I realize I could use `source config_file` and have it set variable; might be the final option. I wanted to know if I could do it like above and simplify the *documentation*.

A simplified example script:

```
# foo.sh
echo "x y z" | xargs set --
echo $*

# Command line
$ bash foo.sh a b c
xargs: set: No such file or directory
a b c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xargs` can't execute `set` because:

1. `set` is a shell built-in, not an external command. `xargs` only knows how to execute commands. (Some shell built-ins shadow commands with the same name, such as `printf`, `true`, and `[`. So `xargs` can execute those commands, but the semantics might not be identical to the built-in.)
2. Even if `xargs` could execute `set`, it would have no effect because `xargs` does not run inside of the shell's environment; every command executed by `xargs` is a separate process. So you will get no error if you do this:

   ```
    echo a b c | xargs bash -c 'set -- "${@}"' _
   ```

   But it also won't do anything useful. (Substitute `set` with `echo` and you'll see that it does actually invoke the command.)

---

#### How to read arguments from a file.

First, you need to answer the question: what does it mean to have arguments in a file? Are they individual whitespace-separated words with no mechanism to include whitespace in any argument? (That would also be required for `xargs` to work in its default mode, so it is not a totally unreasonable assumption, although it is almost certainly going to get you into trouble at some point.)

In that case you don't need `xargs` at all; you can just use command substitution:

```
set -- $(<file)
```

While that will work fine, this won't:

```
echo a b c | set -- $(</dev/stdin)
```

because the pipeline (created by the <kbd>|</kbd> operator) causes the processes on either side to be run in subshells, and consequently the `set` doesn't modify the current shell's environment variables.

---

#### A more robust solution

Suppose that each argument is in a single line in the file, which makes it possible to include whitespace in an argument, but not a newline. Then we could use the useful `mapfile` built-in to read the arguments into an array, and set the positional arguments from the array. (Or just use the array directly, but that would be a different question.)

```
mapfile -t args < file
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

Again, watch out for piping into `mapfile`; it won't work, for the same reason that it didn't work with `set`.

Comment: Terrific answer.  One question: "set is a shell built-in, not an external command. xargs only knows how to execute commands."  --  What is the root of this difference?  From the POV of the implementation of xargs, why does it care?

Comment: @jonah: `xargs` is an external command (that is, an independent program). It's not part of the shell, so it cannot somehow reach into the shell and call a function inside the shell implementation, which is what a shell internal is. `xargs` can, of course, execute a shell itself, but that would be a new, different shell. (I mention that in the answer.) `xargs` can run the same external commands as a shell, because the comands are truly external: they are stand-alone independent programs.

Comment: Thank you.  I see what you were saying now